# Capturing real google search engine terms

Tags: google-search

I use following line for capturing google search referrers but its no longer valid for capturing real people queries

```
$referrer= $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if(preg_match('/(www\.google.*)|(go\.google\.com)/i',$referrer)) {
   $pattern = "/^.*q=([^&]+)&?.*\$/i";
   $query = preg_replace($pattern, '$1', $referrer);
}
```

Google crawls pages like visitors are coming from search engines. I got 22000 following similar search referrers in less than 5 mins

```
http://www.google.co.in/m/search?sa=2&q=xxxx&site=mobile
http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4ACAW_enCA305CA305&q=xxxxx
http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CEwQFjAG&urlhttp://xxxxxxx&rct=j&q=query&ei=Sq2YTpyCMYKOiAKD74jnCQ&usg=AFQjCNEziZmOdqSBoIM_IBo8mZXrmiwkUg&sig2=cno3znIQoQ_wGt_tyWEyqA
```

Any idea how to capture real user search queries?

### EDIT

P.s. Google analytics shows correct number of search referrers, wondering how they assess search referrers?

Answer (score 0):

It's the q=... parameter, but these look wrong to me, as if it wasn't from Google search results. Although you cannot know for sure.